# C# avoid overwritten xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I created a C# Application to write data to xml file. It overrides all the new Data,
How to Avoid..? 
Please help me.
This is my code

```
namespace BarcodeScaner
{
 class WriteFile
 {

    DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;

    public WriteFile()
    {

    }


    public void createFile(string ptr,string value)
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("Data.xml"))
        {

            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Products");

            writer.WriteStartElement("Details");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("PTR", ptr);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Value", value);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("DateTime", dt.ToString());

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do ? append new data ? modify existing file ?

Comment: What do you mean it overrides the new data? Do you mean that you want to append what you are writing to the original document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XmlDocument` to add custom nodes to an existing Xml Document:

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("Data.xml");
  XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("child");
  el.InnerText = "Example of data being appendeed";
  doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(el);
  doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the existing file, add your data to it. And then write the combined results to the file.

Because of the format of XML files, you can't simply append new data to the file as you might with some file formats.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that what you're wanting to do is add new data to an existing XML file, correct?

You can't just append data to an XML file, and your code actually creates a new file each time it's run, overwriting the old one.

What you need to do is read the XML data into memory, add the new nodes, and write the whole file out again.  If there is a lot of data then it may be more efficient to stream from one file to another and insert the new nodes as you go.